# Extjs accordion close all panel dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, accordion, expand

I am using Extjs 5.0.0

I have an accordion with a number of panels. 
Here my requirement is to expand and collapse panel by clicking on the title.

On the first click it expanded, that's fine. while again clicking on the same title i want to collapse all the panels. Here its opening the very next panel.

I just tried by expanding a hidden panel. But here both hidden panel and the next panel to the clicked panel get expanded.

```
listeners:{
    afterrender: function(panel){
        panel.header.el.on('click', function() {
          if (panel.collapsed) {
             Ext.getCmp('hiddenpanel').collapse();
          }
          else {
             Ext.getCmp('hiddenpanel').expand();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a fiddle so that others could understand your issue better.

Comment: Which title did you meant panel title or accordion title?

Comment: Alex, i want panel titles to get the functionality.

Comment: So, you want to collapse all panels on clicking any panel header?  Provide a fiddle with your current code?

Comment: I tried for a fiddle. But it does not have Ext 5.0 library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with opening multiple accordion items at a time,  enable mutli property and set all other panels except the hidden panel collapsed by default will resolve the issue.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
   title: 'Accordion Layout',
   width: 300,
   height: 300,   
   layout: {
      type: 'accordion',      
      animate: true,
      multi: true,
   },
   items: [{
      hidden:true,        
   },{
      title: 'Panel 1',
      html: 'Panel content!',
      collapsed: true
   },{
      title: 'Panel 2',
      html: 'Panel content!',
      collapsed: true
   },{
      title: 'Panel 3',
      html: 'Panel content!',
      collapsed: true
   }],
   renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdazU/397/)

**Edit**: For versions above Ext 5.

```
Ext.application({          
    launch: function() {    
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            autoScroll: true,
            defaults: {
                border: true,
                autoHeight: true,
                minHeight: 304,
                collapsed: true,
                titleCollapse: false
            },
            layout: {
                type: 'accordion',
                animate: true,
                multi: true,
                fill: false
            },
            items: [{
                collapsed: false,
                border: 0,
                height: 0,
                minHeight: 0
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 1'
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 2'
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 3'
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 4'
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 5'
            }],
        });    
    }
});
```

Comment: He wants to collapse all panels on clicking accordion title.

Comment: The hidden panel is a trick I've used before but seems to not work in 4.2.2 or later.

Comment: Making the item hidden seems to cause the accordion to behave as if it isn't there. I'm using this ugly workaround (a zero height item) until I can find a solution I feel good about: {collapsed: false,height: 0}

Comment: any other solution for this issue?

Comment: @AtmiyaDas2014 edited the answer. May be helpful to you.